# Как через Binding скрывать или удалять MenuItem, прикрепленный к ячейке ListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

Есть класс ячейки `ListView`. Внутри при инициализации добавляем

`MenuItem myMenuItem _deleteSwipeButton = new MenuItem
 {
    IsDestructive = true,
 };
ContextActions.Add(myMenuItem);`

Далее на странице, где находится `ListView` происходят какие-то действия. И в какой-то момент для определенных ячеек нужно скрывать `MenuItem`. Т.е. есть условие некое `bool`'евское, по которому можно определить скрывать (или удалять, в данном случае без разницы) `MenuItem` или оставлять у ячейки. Стандартного `Binding`'а я не обнаружил.

У `MenuItem` нет свойства `IsVisibleProperty`.

Возможно, кто-то уже сталкивался с этим и может подсказать, как можно скрывать по условию элемент `MenuItem`?
Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Ловите открытие контекстного меню и выбирайте, что показывать, а что нет.

Comment: @Monk а через binding привязать никак нельзя?

Comment: Конечно можно. Просто раз вы добавляете элементы при инициализации, я предложил аналогичный способ - на запросе для отображения. Можете создать вью_модель для элемента контекстного меню, забиндить его видимость и рулить ею. ПС: я про WPF в основном, остальное надо проверять, но мне не на чём.

Comment: @Monk Тут просто логика несколько иная требуется. Элементы задаются стартово при инициализации и их дальнейшее поведение управляется через биндинги. А действия пользователя уже через них влияет на компоненты, которые были сразу помещены на страницу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наткнулся на следующий вопрос и ответ: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20676/is-it-possible-to-hide-a-toolbaritem

Как у меня заработало:
Добавляем новое свойство для связывания:

`private static readonly BindableProperty MyVisibleProperty = BindableProperty.Create<MyListCell, bool> (ctrl => ctrl.myGetterBool, defaultValue: false,          defaultBindingMode: BindingMode.OneWay, propertyChanging: (bindable, oldValue, newValue) => 
{
   if (oldValue != newValue) 
   { 
      var page = (MyListCell)bindable; 
      if (newValue == true && page.ContextActions.Contains(page.myMenuItem)) 
      { 
         page.ContextActions.Remove(page.myMenuItem);
      } 
      else if (newValue == false && !page.ContextActions.Contains(page.myMenuItem))
       { 
         page.ContextActions.Add(page.myMenuItem);
      } 
   } 
});`

Связывание:

`this.SetBinding<MyViewModel>(MyListCell.MyVisibleProperty, v => v.MyBool);`

MyBool - результат моих проверок (bool)